# Website Overflow Background Colour

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am trying to change the overflow colour of a website. You know when you scroll to the very top, bottom, left or right of a website and try to scroll beyond it and then it automatically goes back, that beyond colour.

Comment: Provide more information

Answer (score 0):

The colour displayed on overflow will usually be the colour of the html **body**